# Websocket creation in js fails for naked domain name

Tags: javascript, java-websocket

I have a web-socket that is started from javascript, that is connecting to a domain (e.g my-domain):

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://www.my-domain.com/ws");
```

If I go in the browser and type www.my-domain.com all works fine. However, for short domain name (i.e. without www) (http://my-domain.com) the opening of the websocket fails.

I have tested on Firefox:
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://www.my-domain.com/ws.

**EDIT: The server is done in GO**:

```
http.HandleFunc("/ws", wsHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)
panic(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))

func (this *server) wsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Header.Get("Origin") != "http://"+r.Host {
        http.Error(w, "Origin not allowed", 403)
        return
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Your dns might not be configured to return an IP address for the naked domain name.  You can compare the results of `ping www.my-domain.com` to the results of `ping my-domain.com` to see if an IP address is returned, or if the name is not found.

Comment: It might be your DNS, but it also might be your server. Ping both the addresses. If they both work, your server is the problem.

Comment: I am not able to ping any of www.my-domain or my-domain.com. I get timeouts on both. Regarding the DNS, if the DNS is not configured for naked name, wouldn't mean that no content would be available when accessing my-domain.com? The html is still received.